# forge jsdelivr is not working in my production environment

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, socket.io, node-forge, jsdelivr

hello please pardon me this is my first time here, I have a node js application that I use in RSA encryption, and on the client side I'm using jsdelivr `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-forge@1.0.0/dist/forge.min.js"></script>` like in the documentation and it works on my Ubuntu perfectly, but for some reason when I place the code in EC2(normal Ubuntu), I get and error regarding prime.workers.js not found, keep notice all my forge operation are client-side I don't do any encryption on the server side.

here is a picture of the error [error_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuCYA.png)
and here is what  i get in the sources[sources_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6wlu.png)

i have tried switching the CDN to Cloudflare but the issue didn't resolve

i want it to work like in my development environment [environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNsuF.png)

all my socket io logic depends on key generation operation here is the snipt  ` generateRSAKeyPair().then(async (keyPair)=>{

const privateKeyPEM = await forge.pki.privateKeyToPem(keyPair.privateKey);
const publicKeyPem =await  forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(keyPair.publicKey)

const socket = io({query:{publicKey:publicKeyPem}});`